# HTML attribute "hasbox"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to solve some rendering issues in IE9 and have come across an tag attribute I'm unfamiliar with - hasbox.

It looks like IE is injecting the attribute at runtime (it's not in my sources). I've searched numerous sites, including stackoverflow, without finding anything useful... the search engines (Google, Bing, Yahoo) return plenty of examples showing html tags with the attribute `hasbox="2"` but otherwise the results are irrelevant.

Can anyone explain this attribute, or point me to a resource where I can learn more?

TIA

Comment: After further testing, this doesn't look to related to IE as it's showing up in Firefox & Chrome as well.

Comment: Tell us more about your hosting account.  For example, GoDaddy injects all kinds of JavaScript and HTML when you use their "Preview DNS" service.

Comment: It's self-hosted, I have complete control over the server (Apache2), it's configuration and the box they're hosted on.

Comment: Also, you say it's not in your _"sources"_ and it looks like it's _"injected at runtime"_, but sometimes WYSIWYG editors will alter your source code upon upload.  For example, GoLive will automatically remove their "livesrc" attribute from any `img` element upon upload.

Comment: Here is a confusing thread where the OP is claiming it's happening in WYSIWYG editor because of Explorer... ???.  Then he closes it out by saying it's being caused by a JavaScript conflict.  [This link.](http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/archive/index.php/t-10369164.html)

Comment: No WYSIWYG editors in the toolchain; we're working on the site using vim on debian squeeze & ubuntu boxes.

Comment: If it's happening in all browsers and your server is not doing it, it has to be happening upon upload.  Try uploading with a different method.

Comment: I'm not uploading - that's why I think it's happening at rendertime.  I'm reading/writing the source files (html, js, css) directly on the server machine.

Comment: Strange!  Since it's happening in all browsers, that only leaves the code itself as the cause.  A JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using a javascript called boxover.js? See http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=150218 and http://web.archive.org/web/20090526084653/http://boxover.swazz.org/

Comment: We do indeed have a copy of this script however our copy's apparently been rebranded.  Was able to confirm using the download at the web-archive page.  Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.webmasterworld.com/html/4013481.htm

This is the only thing I can find about it that isn't being used in an example.

Do you have anything like that installed that could be doing it?

Comment: Unfortunately not - that was actually the first search result I checked as well. It's very odd not to be able to find something related to web development on the 'net.